# Unable to write X_path to get text from application related reports in application,

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, functional-programming, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwt4a.jpg)

In that Image i have tried with xpath using contains also but here class is changing dynamically when ever i run script, i want to get text present in that report

Comment: well if if always changes then you wont be able to grab it, i suggest you talk about this with your development team so they can create an id for the elements you need

Answer (score 0):

You can try for absolute XPath in this case and storing all the `<div>` in a `List<WebElement>`, then selecting the element you want using list index coupled with `getText()` method to fetch the text.